# Quill editor not loading second time visiting the same page in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, quill

I'm initializing quill editor on ngOninit like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    Quill.register('modules/imageDropAndPaste', QuillImageDropAndPaste)
        this.quitinns = new Quill('#editor-container12', {
          modules: {
            toolbar: 
            [
              [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
              ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
              [{ 'list': "ordered" }, { 'list': "bullet" }, { 'indent': "-1" }, { 'indent': "+1" }],
              [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
              [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], 
              ["link", "image", "blockquote"],["table"]
          ],
            imageDropAndPaste: {
              handler: this.imageHandler.bind(this),
            },
          },
          placeholder: 'Copy & paste, or drag an image here...',
          readOnly: false,
          theme: 'snow',
        })
```

html

```
  <div id="editor-container12" #quilledmail></div>
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-drag-and-drop-module

but when visiting the same page it does not load editor for second time only it loads for the first time i visit that route.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Most probably the `ngOnInit` is not being invoked every time you switch components. Check it using a `console.log` statement inside the `ngOnInit`.

Comment: @TheAlpha i have checked within subscribe also i have placed this method `this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {   Quill.register....  }` and console is also called can you pls let me know the issue

Comment: Then, it's probably `Quill` related. I can't say much about it, sorry!